# strong math induction, base case fails?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

For the sequence, a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>k</sub>  , a<sub>0</sub>=5, a<sub>1</sub>=11, a<sub>k</sub>=7a<sub>k-1</sub> - 10a<sub>k-2</sub> for k $\ge$2. Prove a<sub>n</sub> = $3*2^n +2*5^n$, n $\ge$ 0.

The first base case of n=0 works but for n=1,a<sub>0</sub> is 11, but the base case is 16 when substituted in. Does this mean that the proof has failed?

Comment: Yes, the result is just false.

Comment: Well, if the statement is false, it is false.  And the statement *is* false.  Also $a_2 = 7*11 - 10*5 =22\ne 3*2^2 + 2*5^2$. Maybe if the $a_1 =11$ was a typo and supposed to be $a_1 =16$. then $a_2=7*16 - 50=112-50=62=3*4+2*25$ seems to be okay...so maybe the induction step will now work.

Comment: "Yes, the result is just false."  The induction step is valid and the statement is true in every case where the base cases are true.  But if the second base case is just false then the statement is just false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As The statement is not true for $n=1$ then the statement is just false.  Also it is not true for $a_2= 77-50 = 22$.

But if $a_1 = 16$ and the $11$ was a typo we get $a_2 = 7*16-50 = 62 = 3*2^2 + 2*5^2$ and the statement is verified for $n = 2$.

If so maybe the statement is true if we state $a_1 = 16$ instead.

Can we do an induction step?:

If $a_k = 3*2^k + 2*5^k$ and $a_{k-1} = 3*2^{k-1} + 2*5^{k-1}$ then does

$a_{k+1} = 7(3*2^k + 2*5^k) - 10(3*2^{k-1} + 2*5^{k-1}) \overbrace{=}^? 3*2^{k+1} + 2*5^{k+1}$?

That seems like a simple thing to verify (or refute) by simple algebra.

Comment: I got a confirmation, it was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out, thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Can't be doing something wrong if the statement is just wrong.  .... It might be worth noting the induction step *will* always be valid no matter what the base cases are.  But for a proof by induction to be valid you can't just have the induction step valid.  You need the base cases to actually be true as well.  And if they aren't.... they aren't.